# can we shift the query result panel of sql developer to right side like vscode , please tell me?

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

Just like vs code we have terminal in the righ side or in the bottom of line, so is it possible in sql developer to shift the query result panel to right side .

Just like vs code we have terminal in the righ side or in the bottom of line, so is it possible in sql developer to shift the query result panel to right side .

Comment: Query results are usually a mainly horizontal panel, because there are usually many columns to render. I can't recall ever seeing vertical query result panel.

Comment: @Bohemian, I don't think that this was the question. SQL Developer's window is split in two: upper part is used to write queries, procedures, etc. Lower part displays result of those queries; it looks like - as you said - horizontal panel (as if you look at MS Excel spreadsheet). Question - at least, the way I understood it - is to split window horizontally so that queries are written in left hand side part of the window, while result is displayed on the right hand side (but still in a grid like Excel). Anyway: I don't think that this is possible. Can't find such a setting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the application framework we use (FCP delivered via JDeveloper) doesn't support this in what you have available today in Oracle SQL Developer (current version 22.2.1)

However, we're building a new platform and version of SQL Developer, tentatively named 'SQL Developer Next,' and that will definitely be possible.

[image]

*Disclaimer #1: We hope to have this available later in 2023, Early Summer is current best estimate
Disclaimer #2: I work for Oracle and am a product manager for this family of products (SQL Developer)*